# Rails 6 select2 is not defined

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, jquery-select2

Im using rails 6 with webpack, and for some reason I cannot use `select2` when I try to respond a js file the following:

```js
$("#select-search-bar").select2()
```

#### How can I manage to use select2 in the js respond

Here is my `application.js` file:

```
require("@rails/ujs").start()
require("turbolinks").start()
require("@rails/activestorage").start()
require("channels")
require('font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css')
require("jquery")
require('cocoon-rails/src/cocoon')
require('chart.js/dist/Chart')
require('materialize-css/dist/js/materialize')
require('../stylesheets/application')
require('packs/dashboards')
require('packs/relateds')
require('packs/banner')
require('packs/users')
import 'packs/select2'
require('packs/resources')
```

```
// packs/select2.js
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'select2/dist/js/select2.min'
```

Comment: What error message you got when you were using select2() ?

Comment: Function (...).select2 is not defined

Comment: With the little information you've shared it's almost impossible to guess. Please share with us where exactly do you have your file and what's your code's architecture.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is your `app/webpacker/packs/application.js` is not configured correctly.

For example this is what I have:

```
require( 'select2' );
import "select2/dist/css/select2.min.css";
```

Make sure you've added Select2 with `yarn add select2` [see more here](https://classic.yarnpkg.com/en/package/select2). It is possible to have Select2 translated as well by adding your locales like this:

```
require( 'select2/dist/js/i18n/en.js' );
require( 'select2/dist/js/i18n/lv.js' );
```

In case you need bootstrap theme, you can add it as well, for example, Bootstrap3 with `yarn add select2-bootstrap-theme` and then in your `app/webpacker/packs/application.js`

```
import "select2-bootstrap-theme/dist/select2-bootstrap.min.css";
```

In case this doesn't help, probably you have some error in your console and you might be interested to check that.